# Remove everything after a space - Pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a dataframe df as follows:

```
    A               B
  21k2 b            1
  2412 9            p
```

Both A and B are strings.

I would like for the A column elements to be trimmed as follows:

```
  A               B
21k2              1
2412              p
```

Extra thank you points if you can also show how to remove anything before a space.

Comment: that one is pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `split` function and `getItem` method.

```
df = df.select(F.split('A', ' ').getItem(0).alias('A'), 'B')
```

Comment: Would be better to create a split_col variable with the F.split before and use withColumnRenamed if you have many columns